# Interactive grid collapsed control breaks

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a pretty complicated Oracle Apex 19.2 application where on one page we have an IG with up to a couple thousand records. Unfortunately, in order to allow users to insert the data they want, I have to reload the site on every change of a certain type so that they don't mess up the data.

But because the users need to insert quite a bit of this data they want control breaks so that they can collapse the sections they have already completed. Normally these closed control breaks would open back up on every refresh, but I cobbled together some abomination that runs through the IG in javascript before submit and stores which control breaks are closed. And then there is a DA on page load that checks these stored breaks and goes through the IG and tries to close the control breaks.

This works surprisingly well, as long as you don't have many records. Because, well, APEX tries to optimise things and only loads some of the rows from the start, then loads more as you scroll down.

Now that I have explained the background:

Is there any way of forcing an interactive grid to load all its rows from the start, even if it takes a bit longer?

Or perhaps do you brilliant people have a better idea how to restore those collapsed control breaks?

Thank you for any ideas you may have.

Comment: I have a similar requirement to collapse few rows in IG. The rows in IG are fixed. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Hey @Vini I never did get it to work properly, because oracle only loads up the rows it will actually display, so I could only collapse the first 50 or so rows.
If that works for you I can get that code for you?
Or maybe if you want to go and play around with it, maybe you can figure out how to make it work on all rows?

Comment: This is my requirement: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66703367/oracle-apex-collapse-interactive-grid-rows The data is dummy. I have in reality 14 rows. And just like in the example in the thread, i need to collapse few rows in between. Collapse them by default and then they can be expanded. If you can share the code that might help, it would be great. Also in my case, number of rows for grid will always be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In order to fetch all records to your IG region, you need to use IG JavaScript API method `model.fetchAll()`.

1. Set static ID for your IG region (Advanced > Statid ID), e.g. `igRegionId`.
2. Create new `Page Load` dynamic action.
3. Add a `TRUE action` of type `Execute JavaScript Code` to dynamic action.
4. Put sample JavaScript code to `Setting > Code` attribute of your `TRUE action`.

   let ig = apex.region("igRegionId").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews","grid");
   ig.model.fetchAll(function(response){
   console.log(response);
   });

`fetchAll` gets rows from database chunked by `pageSize` (default 50 records). In `response` callback parameter is object with info about data offset, total records and is fetching is done.

Comment: I tried this, but it still doesent seem to work.
If I check the page out in console I can see that after the first 40 or so rows comes a row called a-GV-scrollFiller which seems to make it so it still only loads the records once you scroll down.