# Oracle Apex Collapse Interactive grid rows

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I have a grid and i need to collapse few rows in the grid.
The number of rows will always remain constant.

Ex:
[image]

So 3rd and 4th rows will be collapsible here.

How can this be achieved?

Apex 20.2

Comment: Do you have control breaks set up already??
Not sure if you can collapse individual rows, control breaks are basically grouping based on one column, so then you can collapse all the rows where that column is identical together.
If you do, then I can probably help you

Comment: I have control breaks option in action menu, but not sure how i can use them here to collapse rows.

Comment: Control breaks work for columns i guess, how can i do those for rows?

Comment: what sort of output are you expecting here, do you want it so that those two rows are just not seen? Do you want it so that those two rows will be hidden into one single row that can be expanded?

Comment: I want the arrow/control on 2nd row. So when its clicked, the 3rd and 4th rows are expanded. And on page load the 3rd and 4th rows remain hidden/collapsed by default.

Comment: Maybe try playing around with a column which indicates if this field will be collapsed or not, then set a control break on that column and see if this is the output you want.

Comment: In case of control breaks, there is just option to select column and ascending/descending. Even if i set a flag value in the grid query, how will i use that here? for ex: in case of highlighting  columns, i set flg and give that as condition to highlight. But how do i define that condition in column breaks?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230114/discussion-between-tineo-and-vini).